# How can I access the binding properties of a XAML object, from my code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

I would like to access the binding settings for a control in a XAML document, from within my C# code.  Specifically, I'd like to set a breakpoint in my code and using the Visual Studio's Locals window, I'd like to inspect the properties associated with a bound control, from within the VS debugger.

Can this be done?

In my case I have a `TextBox` with binding defined in my XAML file. I have a `StringFormat` specified in my binding statement and I'd like to see where the string formatter details are stored within my `TextBox`.  After setting a breakpoint, and inspecting the `TextBox` for a while, I cannot find the underlying binding properties?!

I assume there has to be a way for me to be able to access my binding settings from my ViewModel code.  Where are these binding settings stored?

NOTE: I know that the `DataContext` contains the data object that my control is interacting upon.  However, that is not what I need.  I need to see, and inspect, the settings that wire the data object with the XAML UI object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access from your code behind using below code.

```
BindingExpression be= txt.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        string format=be.ParentBinding.StringFormat;
```

Comment: Ah, so I assume these details are contained in a *mysterious* property or collection, so I'll have to query the information from a property.  Ok, if this gets me what I need, after my tests, I'll give you the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: This is the answer.  Thank you. I'll need to post a follow-up.  In my case, I need to be able to toggle the StringFormat value and, apparently, .Net doesn't like it when you try to change a binding setting after the binding has been used.  I'll post a link to the follow-up question, in case you know that answer as well.  Thank you.

Comment: and here is the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751867/how-can-i-change-i-e-toggle-the-bound-stringformat-property-of-a-wpf-control