# How can I change (i.e. toggle) the bound, StringFormat property of a WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting, code-behind

I have a WPF `TextBox` that has it's text value bound in XAML.  This works fine and, as expected, when the associated value is loaded to the field, it is formatted as desired.

My issue is when the user enters the text field to modify the value, I want to strip away the formatting, and display the raw underlying value.

To do this, I tried to set the `BindingExpression.ParentBinding.StringFormat` property, on the text boxes binding from within a `GotFocus` event.  However, when I tried to set the `StringFormat` property to an empty string, I got the following exception:

> Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.

So, after a control has been bound to a data model object, is there a straight-forward way that I can modify the string format of the `TextBox`?  I'm willing to change how I format the value of the control, but the end desire is to strip the formatting of the data when it is being edited, and re-instating the string formatting once the user exits the field.

Comment: recently i have done similar thing. Refer the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643298/wpf-custom-textbox-with-decimal-formatting/28661951#28661951

Comment: Lol, thanks @Ganesh.  That's exactly what I need.  If I can't figure out a way to do this without creating a new control, I'll use your implementation (and give Ryan the answer mark, since that's his suggestion.)  However, I might have found a way to do this with styles and triggers... I'll need to experiment and update this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try it differently. It sounds like you are using the same TextBox for the formatted value and editing the raw value. It would be cleaner to use two different TextBoxes for View and Edit, or package it in a `UserControl`. Also, I would use two properties, e.g. `RawText` and `FormattedText`, and the `UserControl` would have DependencyProperties with bindings to both properties. The `UserControl` would automatically switch to the Edit TextBox. The question of "how does the automatic switching" work may be a challenge though. You probably need to use the GotFocus of the View TextBox as you mentioned, although it might not be a bad idea to have an actual `Edit` button that switches it for you.

I understand about switching to WPF. There is quite a bit of adjustment (aka learning) when switching to WPF. I would think of it as designing a form or control that is "fit for purpose". You don't have to create a new UserControl though. You could do something similar to StackOverflow where there is an Edit TextBox and then the View area, that would be equivalent to the Raw and Formatted values. You would control the Visibility of the Edit TextBox through a [BoolToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) when you are in edit mode. Create a `public bool IsEditing` property on your ViewModel and bind that to the `<EditTextBox Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Text="{Binding RawText}" ...etc... />`  After working with WPF for a while, you really appreciate data binding and it makes it hard to go back to plain WinForms (at least for me - not to say there aren't challenges though!).

Comment: This might be the best answer however... I have a hard time accepting that to change the format of a value I have to override the control for such a simple task.  PS: This is my first WPF project, and I've been coding WinForms since .Net 1.0.  I *might* be acting like a spoiled brat :P

Comment: Thanks for the update but unfortunately I'm in a corporate environment.  I have a tightly-specified design document and this has been explicitly specified and is a rather firm requirement by the user.  C'est la vie.

Comment: I understand about requirement docs. Same here. Just remember, revising a bad requirement is better than a poor implementation of a bad requirement. If the requirement is a single control, then I'd go with the UserControl suggestion and get that working.